# Can I make the following assumptions about the longest simple circuits?

Tags: graph-theory

The longest simple circuit in $W_n$ is $\frac{3}{2}n$ when $n$ is even and $\frac{3}{2}(n-1) + 1$ when $n$ is odd.

I drew it out for a couple of graphs and it seemed to work. Can someone confirm this?

[image: Picture]

For example for $W_{10}$ the answer is $\frac{3}{2}(10) = 15$. I know the answer should be 15 based on an example question and answer that I used to practice for a test.

Comment: How are you defining a simple circuit? I would have just said $n -1$ for the longest simple circuit- go around the wheel of $n - 1$ elements. I'm obviously missing something?

Comment: Can you include any of your drawings?

Comment: @ColmBhandal I think what you are refering to is $C_n$, the cyclic graph. Here's how $W_n$ would be defined https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph

Comment: I suppose that repeated vertices are allowed in your circuits (just not edges)?

Comment: @Anthony my confusion was over the definition of "simple circuit" rather than the wheel graph itself.

Comment: From this definition of simple circuit: http://www.mathcove.net/petersen/lessons/get-lesson?les=20, the wheel graph seems to have an $n - 1$ simple circuit, unless I am missing something really obvious (which I feel I am)?

Comment: @ColmBhandal yes sorry my fault. I would assume simple circuit would be Hamiltonian cycles?

Comment: No, a simple circuit is a circuit that doesn't include the same edge twice and finishes and starts at the same vertex.

Comment: @ColmBhandal I will add a picture.

Comment: @Julia- slow day for me- I thought your question said $\frac23n$ not $\frac32n$- hence all the triviality

Answer (score 2):

For a wheel graph $W_{2n}$ with hub $w$ and outer vertices $v_1,\ldots, v_{2n}$ we can form the circuit
$$wv_1v_2wv_3v_4w\ldots wv_{2n-1}v_{2n}$$
of length $3n$. A longer circuit is not possible because eacxh $v_i$ cannot appear more than once and between tow occurances of $w$ there must be two $v_i$.

Similarly, for a wheel graph $W_{2n+1}$ with hub $w$ and outer vertices $v_1,\ldots, v_{2n+1}$ we can form the circuit
$$wv_1v_2wv_3v_4w\ldots wv_{2n-1}v_{2n}v_{2n+1}$$
of length $3n+1$. Again alonger circuit is not possible because eacxh $v_i$ cannot appear more than once and between tow occurances of $w$ there must be two $v_i$.